# UNIX timestamp generator MATLAB

Tags: matlab, unix-timestamp

Is there an easy to use function in MATLAB to generate UNIX timestamps in millisecond precision. Somehow, in my search so far, I only come across human readable formats.

Answer (score 3):

instruction `now` will return the number of days from Jan 0, 0000.

You can use the following formula to convert it to Unix time (note that I multiplied by 1000 to obtain the results in milliseconds instead of seconds).

`int32(floor(60*60*24 * (datenum(now) - datenum('01-Jan-1970')))) * 1000`

**EDIT**: I see that the returned value is not exactly the same as the one returned by http://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Returned value:     1471866676

From unixtimestamp: 1471859475

It differs by 116 minutes more o less. It might have something to do with leap seconds.

Answer (score 1):

`int32(posixtime(datetime()))` returns an integer number of seconds. You can, of course, multiply that by 1000 to get milliseconds, but I don't know how to read the clock to millisecond precision.

Documentation says `posixtime` and `datetime` were introduced in Matlab R2014b.

EDIT: Documentation says `posixtime` includes fractional seconds. So I guess you can multiply it by 1000 and take the integer part to get milliseconds.